# What does React do when a page reloads after a route parameter is passed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router-dom

The technology stack I use is React+TS+React-Router-V6
Now the page will pass parameters after clicking the button, and the page can change in real time and receive the parameters passed (as shown in the figure below).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dezpy.gif)

But I hope I can achieve the same effect as the following picture, the page will be re-rendered after clicking. I used useEffect to capture id parameters, but there was no effect, what should I do to achieve the same effect as the following picture

The parameter of my route parameter is id. The route is defined as follows.

```
const routes: RouteObject[] = [
  { path: "/", element: <Navigate to="/discover" /> },
  {
    path: "/discover",
    element: <Discover />,
    children: [
      { path: "/discover", element: <Navigate to="/discover/recommend" /> },
      { path: "/discover/recommend", element: <Recommend /> },
      { path: "/discover/ranking", element: <Ranking /> },
      { path: "/discover/singers", element: <Singers /> },
      { path: "/discover/songs", element: <Songs /> },
      { path: "/discover/album", element: <Album /> },
      {
        path: "/discover/djradio",
        element: <DJRadio />,
        children: [
          { path: "/discover/djradio/category", element: <Category /> },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  { path: "/mine", element: <Mine /> },
  { path: "/focus", element: <Focus /> },
  { path: "/download", element: <Download /> },
];
export default routes;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIzbq.gif)

Here is the code for my component

```
import { Carousel } from "antd";
import React, { ReactNode, useEffect, useRef, memo, ElementRef } from "react";
import { Outlet, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { getRadioDataAction } from "./store";
import { useBearDispatch, useBearSelector } from "@/store";
import { RadioWrapper } from "./style";
import { RadioItemWrapper } from "./style";
import classNames from "classnames";
import { useQuery } from "@/utils/useQuery";
interface IProps {
  children?: ReactNode;
}

const DJRadio: React.FC<IProps> = () => {
  const dispatch = useBearDispatch();
  const ref = useRef<ElementRef<typeof Carousel>>(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { id } = useQuery();
  const currentID = id;
  const { catelist } = useBearSelector((state) => ({
    catelist: state.radio.catelist,
  }));
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getRadioDataAction());
  }, [id]);
  function handleChange(isNext: boolean) {
    if (isNext) {
      ref.current?.next();
    } else {
      ref.current?.prev();
    }
  }
  function handleClickTo(id: number) {
    const wantUrl = "/discover/djradio/category?id=" + id;
    navigate(wantUrl);
  }
  return (
    <RadioWrapper className="all-bg">
      <div className="wrap-v2 content">
        <div className="content-top">
          <div
            className="my-left sprite-dj-btn"
            onClick={() => {
              handleChange(false);
            }}
          ></div>
          <Carousel className="carousel" ref={ref}>
            {[0, 1].map((item: any, index: number) => {
              return (
                <div className="dj-content" key={index}>
                  {catelist &&
                    catelist
                      .slice(index * 18, (index + 1) * 18)
                      .map((element: any) => {
                        return (
                          <RadioItemWrapper
                            key={element.id}
                            imgUrl={element.picWebUrl}
                            onClick={() => handleClickTo(element.id)}
                            className={classNames({
                              active: currentID == element.id,
                            })}
                          >
                            <div className="img-content">
                              <div className="item-img"></div>
                            </div>

                            <span className="item-name">{element.name}</span>
                          </RadioItemWrapper>
                        );
                      })}
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </Carousel>
          <div
            className="my-right sprite-dj-btn"
            onClick={() => {
              handleChange(true);
            }}
          ></div>
        </div>
        <div>{id}</div>
        <Outlet></Outlet>
      </div>
    </RadioWrapper>
  );
};
export default memo(DJRadio);
```

a page reloads after a route parameter is passed

Comment: Sorry, perhaps it's a language barrier, but the animated screen gifs don't make it clear what exactly it is you want to demonstrate. Without seeing your route declarations it's also unclear what route parameters you are referring to. Can you [edit] the post to clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi, I want to re-render (like refresh) the second image after routing the parameter (id).

Comment: What needs to be rerendered or refreshed? What would trigger this? I don't see any routes with parameters. Are you referring the URL queryString params, specifically the `id` query param? From what I can understand of your code it's already a dependency of the `useEffect` hook. Is the component not rerendering as expected when you navigate with a new `id`queryString param value?

Comment: Now when I click each button, the parameter id  will be passed to the route. I hope that the page will be refreshed after clicking each button (as shown in Figure 2), but I do not have such an effect when I click now.

Comment: Ok, yeah, `id` isn't anything that `react-router` cares about since it's not part of any route path. What is the issue with the `id` query param when it changes? The `useEffect` hook isn't triggered? Is this `useQuery` hook reading the `id` from the queryString? Can you add that code to your post?

Comment: I want the whole page to be rerendered when the id parameter changes. Should I change my routing configuration? How should I modify it? Thanks.

Comment: IDK, it should just rerender when the route changes. I'm guessing that you are really asking for the `useEffect` hook to be rerun though. What is the issue you are trying to fix that you think reloading the page will resolve?

Comment: It works fine now, but I just want a reload effect. useEffect does not rerender when used.

Comment: Oh, so there's no problem with your code, you just want a page reload "effect"? I don't understand why anyone would want that but I suppose you could call [`window.location.reload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) to do this.

Comment: So you want the `Category` component that is rendered on `"/discover/djradio/category"` to "reload" when the `id` queryString param updates?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was going for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just want a reload effect. useEffect does not rerender when used.

The `useEffect` is run as the result of the component having been rendered; it doesn't itself cause any rerenders or page reloads.

A trivial solution to "reload" the `"/discover/djradio/category"` page would be to call [`window.location.reload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) from a `useEffect` hook in `Category` when the `id` queryString parameter value changes.

Example:

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Category = () => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const id = searchParams.get("id");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.location.reload();
  }, [id]);

  ...
};
```

This would actually make a network request to the server for the page/react app and might not be ideal. You could fake a reload with some state that just conditionally renders null for a second or to and then switches back to the `Category` UI JSX.

Example:

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Category = () => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

  const id = searchParams.get("id");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);

    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    }, 3000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, [id]);

  ...

  if (loading) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc...
  }

  ...
};
```